# Enteprise Architect element MiscData(0) change (PDATA1)

Tags: add-in, enterprise-architect

I guess it's a simple question, but i still couldn't figure out how can i change the `PDATA1`/`MiscData(0)` property of an element via Add-In (and not by **SQL** Update). The problem is that the documentation says the `MiscData` is read-only.

Basically i am trying to make a `hyper-link` on a diagram with the help of an Add-In.
I create a simple Text typed `EA.Element`, then an `EA.DiagramObject`, connect them via `ElementID` and i need this Text typed object to point to an exact diagram.

What i know is that a `hyper-link` is a Text typed object with `PDATA1` filled in with the wanted diagram's `ID`. The created element's Notes is already filled with a valid hyperlink's value like: `packageName : diagramName`.

I'm interested in any other ways to make a working `hyper-link` with the help of an Add-In.

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Tamas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

```
Repository.Execute("UPDATE t_object set PDATA1 ...")
```

`Execute` is an undocumented but ever since working last resort. Nobody knows why MiscData is r/o.

In oder to make the changes visible on the diagram you need to call

```
Repository.ReloadDiagram (diagram.DiagramID)
```

Since EA will eventually pop-up a save-window for modified diagrams you should eventually call

```
Repository.SaveDiagram (diagram.DiagramID)
```

prior to the reload.

**Important note**: You need to remember that the `Execute` bypasses the API. If you have diagram changes and call `Execute` on diagram objects they need to be saved before. EA only updates all changed diagram objects in the database when the whole diagram is saved (manually or via `SaveDiagram`).

Comment: I forgot a really important fact: it is a local .eap file i want the Add-In to work with, i cannot use SQL Update.

Comment: It will work with any database (even .eap) in this way.

Comment: Alright, sorry, one more thing: it will surely not work in my case. Any other guesses?

Anyways, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @geert: Thanks for the fix :-)

Comment: Why won't it work in your case? Except for totally bypassing EA's API this is the only way to go.

Comment: I thought i cannot use UPDATE, that my permissions are restricted to only SELECTS, but no: what should i call after Execute? I'm testing it with a Script within EA - if i add this link element to the diagram it is still not a hyperlink, but after running the script again the latest added element becomes a link, the currently added always stays simple Text.

Comment: There is no checking done by EA as to who is issuing that call. EA is not secure in any way. If you have trolls that have access to the database (and that's pretty much every modeler) you are at a loss.

Comment: My problem was: at first always create the EA.Element + the EA.DiagramObject, call Update to both of them and to the Diagram, THEN use Repository.Execute to see the changes. Thank you for your help! ReloadDiagram and SaveDiagram is not necessary if it is currently not opened.